# Как обработать переменную типа TextField что бы исключить ошибку

Tags: java, javafx

Использую `mvc` в `javaFx` если не буду указывать значение во всех вводимых полях `TextField` то получу ошибку:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

А мне для решения не всегда нужно указывать все 5 значений. Как обработать переменную `myTextField5`

в классе контроллер

```
@FXML
public void solve() throws Exception {
    this.go();
}

private void go() {
    // отдаем классу модель нужные данные
    model.setNum1(parseDouble(myTextField1.getText()));
    model.setNum2(parseDouble(myTextField2.getText()));
    model.setNum3(parseDouble(myTextField3.getText()));
    model.setNum4(parseDouble(myTextField4.getText()));

    model.setNum5(parseDouble(myTextField5.getText()));

    model.setCheckBox1(checkbox1);
    model.setCheckBox2(checkbox2);
    model.setCheckBox3(checkbox3);
    model.setCheckBox4(checkbox4);

    // вычисляем результат
    model.go();
```

Класс модель

```
public class Model {

private double k;
private double krit;
private double zapas;
private String g;

private double a;
private double b;
private double t;
private double e;
private double f;

private double c;

private CheckBox checkbox1;
private CheckBox checkbox2;
private CheckBox checkbox3;
private CheckBox checkbox4;

private Double result;

void setNum1(Double s) { a = s; }

void setNum2(Double s) { b = s; }

void setNum3(Double s) { t = s; }

void setNum4(Double s) { e = s; }

void setNum5(Double s) { f = s; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось простым не обходимо было в set поменяться добавить условие проверки.

```
  private void go(){
    // отдаем классу модель нужные данные


    model.setNum1(parseDouble(myTextField1.getText()));
    model.setNum2(parseDouble(myTextField2.getText()));
    model.setNum3(parseDouble(myTextField3.getText()));
    model.setNum4(parseDouble(myTextField4.getText()));


 if(myTextField5.getText().equals("")){
    myTextField5.setPromptText("Уточните значение");
    myTextField5.clear();

 }
 else
```

{